# null response when calling lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

My lambda function is returning a null response and I'm not sure why. When I change 'res.body' to 'res.statusCode' I get the status code 200 as expected. I've checked the logs of my api call and see that there are no issues with the details I am passing (also confirmed using a curl command. Any ideas?

```
const https = require('https');

function getRequest() {


const options = {
    host: 'vehimgd36c3.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com',
    path: '/callinglink',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'link': 'https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda.Function.html'
    }
}

return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
https.get(options, (res) => {
    resolve(res.body)
  }).on('error', (e) => {
    reject(Error(e))
  })
})
```

}

```
exports.GetReturnMessage = async (event) => {
try {
    const result = await getRequest();
    console.log(result)
    

    return {

        "sessionState": {
            "dialogAction": {
                "type": "Close"

            },
            "intent": {
                "confirmationState": "Confirmed",
                "name": "FinalResponse",
                "state": "InProgress",
            },
        },
        "messages": [

            {
                "contentType": "CustomPayload",
                "content": result
            },

        ]

    };

} catch (error) {
    console.log('Error is: ️', error);
    return {
        statusCode: 400,
        body: error.message,
    };
}
```

};

Answer (score 0):

If you check how to use lambda and apigateway. apigateway expects the lamba function to return a response with the structure [Read here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-apigateway.html)

```
var response = {
      "statusCode": 200,
      "body": "{\n  \"TotalCodeSize\": 104330022,\n  \"FunctionCount\": 26\n}"
    }
```

in that case you could try returning your object as follows:

```
exports.GetReturnMessage = async (event) => {
    try {
        const result = await getRequest();
        console.log(result)


        const response = {

            "sessionState": {
                "dialogAction": {
                    "type": "Close"

                },
                "intent": {
                    "confirmationState": "Confirmed",
                    "name": "FinalResponse",
                    "state": "InProgress",
                },
            },
            "messages": [

                {
                    "contentType": "CustomPayload",
                    "content": result
                },

            ]

        };

        return {
            "statusCode": 200,
            "body": JSON.stringify(response)
        }

    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error is: ️', error);
        return {
            statusCode: 400,
            body: error.message,
        };
    }
}
```